# Change HTTP images path used by Compass

Tags: compass-sass, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm using Yeoman with Compass to compile the bootstrap SASS files.  My Yeoman app is not in the base directory of my web server, it's in a directory called "ui".  I'm getting 404 not found for the bootstrap images because the CSS files are pointing to /images when they should be pointing to /ui/images.  I've tried modifying the compass options in my Gruntfile as below but it doesn't seem to change anything in the generated CSS:

```
      compass: {
        options: {
            sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
            cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
            imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
            javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
            fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
            importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
            httpImagesPath: '/ui/images',
            httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/ui/images/generated',
            relativeAssets: false
        },
        dist: {},
        server: {
            options: {
                debugInfo: true
            }
        }
    },
```

It doesn't seem to make a difference if I set relativeAssets equal to true or false.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Yeoman app has been generated by [generator-webapp](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp) and includes bootstrap 2.x.x, you can see the following code in app/styles/main.scss.

```
  $iconSpritePath: "../images/glyphicons-halflings.png";
  $iconWhiteSpritePath: "../images/glyphicons-halflings-white.png";
```

You can modify these paths as you like.

Comment: Awesome!  I was making this more complicated then it was.  thanks!